# TextBlock displaying list of objects

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

If I use following code to display objects in a `ListBox`, how can I display it in a `TextBlock`?

```
listStudents.Items.Clear();
foreach (Student sRef in StudentList)
{
    listStudents.Items.Add(sRef);
}
```

Comment: Change your data template on the ListBox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to display several lines of students in *a single* `TextBlock`, you could append to the `Text` property of the `TextBlock`:

```
foreach (Student sRef in StudentList)
{
    textBlock1.Text += sRef.Firstname + " " sRef.Lastname + Environment.NewLine;
}
```

But you probably want to define an `ItemTemplate` that defines the appearance of each `Student` object in the view:

```
<ListBox x:Name="listStudents">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Firstname}" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Lastname}" Margin="2 0 0 0" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
listStudent.Items.Clear();
        foreach (Student sRef in StudentList)
        {
            listSubjects.Items.Add(sRef.firstname + " " + sRef.lastname);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want just to display a list of objects without selection and other `ListBox` functionality, it's convenient to use `ItemsControl` - it has `ItemTemplate` property to control an appearance of each item and other useful stuff (actually, `ListBox` inherits `ItemsControl`). Just use `itemsStudent` variable of type `ItemsControl` and use the same code:

```
itemsStudent.Items.Clear();
foreach (Student sRef in StudentList)
{
    itemsStudent.Items.Add(sRef);
}
```